# HTTP ERROR 500 Asp.NET

Tags: c#, http

Tengo en mi codigo js

```
var Objeto = new Object();
Objeto.Layout = $('#files').text();
 $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: "Monitoreo.aspx/Leerlayout",
         data: '{Data:' + JSON.stringify(Objeto) + '}',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
         dataType: 'json',
         async: true,
         success: function (Resultado) {
           ///////
         }
```

y en la parte de mi aspx la declaracion del metodo LeerLayout,

```
[WebMethod]
public static String LeerLayout(Mdl_Historico Data)
{
   //// 
}
```

pero me manda el error 500 indicando que hubo un problema el servidor se encontró una condición imprevista que le impidió completar la solicitud. asp.net
lo mas extraño es que solo me pasa al montarlo en un servidor, no encuentro cual es el problema aqui, si de la misma manera tengo asignados otros metodos y los llamo desde ajax de la misma manera.

Comment: si usas la developer tools del browser (al cual accedes con F12), en la solapa `network` podrias inspeccionar a cual url esta queriendo acceder y que datos les pasa para ver si esta respondiendo

Answer (score 0):

Aconsejaria que armes el objeto que envias usando javascript class en lugar de combinar una mezcla

algo como esto

```
 var Objeto = {
       Data: {
              Layout: $('#files').text()
             }
      };


 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "Monitoreo.aspx/Leerlayout",
     data: JSON.stringify(Objeto),
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     dataType: 'json',
```

entonces todo se serializa con el `JSON.stringify()`